Why Microsoft Entra ID's Identifier (EntityID) doesn't match Metadata XML EntityID?
I'm setting up a nodeJs SAML application. My users can create an org, connect it to Azure Entra ID and authenticate against Entra.
I want to enable my users to set up their SAML connection to Azure using only a Metadata XML from their app in Azure Entra ID.
Unfortunately I get an error about Identifier(EntityID) mismatch when I use EntityID from Metadata XML that I'd downloaded from the Azure App. When I use the Identifier from Azure authentication works.
I managed to set up a connection for an AWS' app to Azure using only a Metadata XML file so I think it should be possible for my NodeJs app as well.
Also in Azure App settings is said that there's the default Identifier and it's the audience of the SAML response for IDP-initiated SSO but I don't receive audience in metadata because in my case it's not IDP-initiated SSO, it's service provider initiated SSO.
@node-saml/passport-saml handles SAML on my NodeJs server. I set these settings to authenticate a user: callbackURL, issuer (EntityId), entryPoint, certificate.
